# What is bubbling in Sencha Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

There is a method in sencha extjs components called 'Bubble', the method looks like this `bubble( fn, [scope], [args] )` .
I would like to know what is this method used for and maybe an example.

Another method looks like `enableBubble( eventNames )`

Looked at documentation still wont explain it, If the question is not clear maybe i can refine it. I would just like to understand in terms of sencha extjs what is a bubble primarily used for.

My version of the framework is **Ext JS 5.1.x**
Thanks!

Comment: I got this method from Ext.button.Button

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button

Comment: What part of [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-bubble) are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I just dont understand what a bubble is for I read here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.button.Button.html#method-bubble  the concept is just escaping me

Comment: so what i think it mean is if i call a function in a component that has nested components it will call each function inside nested components, this whole thing is confusing. Trying to use it to see its usefullness in my application

Comment: There's no "primary use". If you need to execute some function on a component and the ancestor components above it, you can use that.

Comment: Ah I see that explains it more clearly, does someone have an example to a link somewhere i can study

Answer (score 0):

[Bubbling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_bubbles.asp) is not a extjs specific concept.
It is a property of any `event`.

An even better description of [bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) events can be found here

event.bubbles specifies whether the event will bubble or not in native js.

I'm assuming(to be corrected) that `enableBubble(click)` allows click event, which is tied to a scope to bubble outside of the scope to the parent `scope` or parent `element`.